# Python VSCode can't open file [Errno 22]

Tags: python, file, conda

I'm just trying to run python in VSCode, but everytime I try, it spits this out into the terminal.

```
>> & C:/Users/caleb/anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/caleb/OneDrive/Desktop/Programmin'/Projects/blackjack/blackjack.py
C:\Users\caleb\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmin\Projects\blackjack\blackjack.py
& C:\Users\caleb\anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmin\Projects\blackjack\blackjack.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
PS C:\Users\caleb\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmin'\Projects\blackjack>
```

I've seen others get the `[Errno 22]`, but only when calling the `open()` function; this happens when all that I have in the file is `print('hello world')`. For them, the problem was the backslashes in the file name, I can see that my paths have varying slashes, but I don't know what to do to fix it. I tried looking in my environment variables, but nothing seemed off there.

Comment: Do you literally have an apostrophe in your folder name?  Please remove that.  It's only going to cause you grief.  You can see in the error message that the command processor has already removed it